# gMTP counterpart for Kindle Paperwhite?

Tags: 12.04, kindle

I plan to buy a Kindle Paperwhite.

In all discussions so far about connecting the Kindle Paperwhite to Ubuntu, I have seen only answers/comments that suggest how to connect Kindle Fire to Ubuntu, and I have seen that Kindle Fire doesn't appear that Kindle Paperwhite uses MTP under firmware versions 5.3.1 or 5.3.3. So far I don't have a clear picture about whether data transfer is possible between Ubuntu 12.04 and Kindle Paperwhite.

I want to know

**(i)** Which firmware versions *for sure* use MTP, so that gMTP does the trick for me, so that I can select the right Kindle Paperwhite firmware version.

**(ii)** If there are none, then does there exist a universal solution for some/all the available firmware versions of Kindle available in the market.

I want to get this done ***without rooting***.

Comment: think you should go for kindle support center.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a Kindle Paperwhite. The current firmware revision is 5.3.4, and is what a new Kindle Paperwhite will come with. It works using USB mass storage. Simply plug it in to the USB, and copy over the PDFs or files you wish to put on the Kindle.

Answer (score 1):

The Kindle Paperwhite is mounted as a simple USB storage disk. There is no need for a special software to read/write data from it.

To manage otherwise purchased ebooks, I use and recommend Calibre.